# how to simulate and get "bad_alloc "exception?

Tags: out-of-memory, bad-alloc

Can anyone tell me how to simulate and produce the `bad_alloc` exception in C++? In my code in some places i am using `new` operator which will throw the `bad_alloc` exception. I want to simulate this scenario and need to test the code.

Answer (score 1):

Balamurugan,

I had the same doubt this afternoon, and did not see anything related here.
So I went to  [CPlusPlus](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/) and put the try catch inside an infinite loop, and worked. Under VS C++ 2010 Express.

Below my code:

```
// bad_alloc standard exception
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
  unsigned int count=0;
  while (1) 
  {
    count++;
    try
     {
      int* myarray= new int[1000000];
     }
     catch (exception& e)
     {
    cout << "Standard exception: " << e.what() << endl;
    cout << "\nAborting after "<< count << " loops";
    return -1;
     }
   }
cout<<"\nNormal finishing...";
return 0;
}
```

In my case, it was caught after 523 loops. I would be better if i knew a setting to limit the heap to Fisical Memory, if I find I'll make you know.